# Titanium Mobile: Slide to switch between the views

Tags: android, ios, gesture, titanium-mobile

I am developing a mobile app using Titanium. I came across the Google Plus, Tweetdeck, Market Apps for Android. To switch between the tabs they use the slide gesture. Its like the next view simply slides in based on your swipe/drag. I would also like to add the same kind to behavior for my app I would like to have it work on both Android and iOS platforms. How can I have it?
I have tried Ti.UI.scrollableView. The problems I faced were

- The sliding was not as responsive as seen in the above apps.
- The view does not move along with the finger drag. It moves after the finger drag is finished.
- It seems to take more memory as the application response slows drastically and animations dont appear to be smooth.

Kindly let me know if there is any other alternative to implement this kind of experience in the app.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is a Ti.UI.ScrollableView which implements the native Android ViewPager. Those other Apps are binding their Tabs to the ViewPager. You can't do this with a Ti.UI.TabGroup but you can either use your own Tab views or some other module that provides this functionality like [this](https://github.com/ghahramani/viewpager). You could also have a look at my Alloy widget [here](https://github.com/manumaticx/pagingcontrol) - it provides a custom tab-indicator for Ti.UI.ScrollableView (without another module).

Answer (score 0):

For Android you should consider using a third-party library to implement such functionality.

Personally I use [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip) which I have found that works really well.